# How to get the answer to show starting from the nth element of an integer (collatz sequence)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example if `d = 50` and
`n = 5`
then I'd like the answer to start at the 5th term of 50 which is 44
this is my code:

```
print('choose two whole numbers')
d = int(input("d: "))
n = int(input("n: "))
cpt=0
while d != 1:
    if (d % 2 == 0): #% checks remainder, if 0 - odd, if 1 - even 
        d = d/2
        print(d)
    else:
        d = (3*d)+1    
    cpt+=1
print('d is reached at '+str(cpt)+'th term')
```

this is the output I'm getting:

```
choose two whole numbers
d: 50
n: 5

25.0
38.0
19.0
29.0
44.0
22.0
11.0
17.0
26.0
13.0
20.0
10.0
5.0
8.0
4.0
2.0
1.0
d is reached at 24th term
```

what I need is for it to start showing the results from the n-th value in this case 5th term like this:

```
choose two whole numbers
d: 50
n: 5

44.0
22.0
11.0
17.0
26.0
13.0
20.0
10.0
5.0
8.0
4.0
2.0
1.0

d is reached at 24th term
```

any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Inside `while` loop, `if cpt >= n: print(d)`

Comment: Or again inside `while` loop, `n--; if n==0: print(d)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build up the sequence and only start printing at your `nth` item then:

```
print('choose two whole numbers')
d = int(input("d: "))
n = int(input("n: "))
# cpt = 0
result = []

while d != 1:
    if (d % 2 == 0): #% checks remainder, if 0 - odd, if 1 - even 
        d = d/2
        #print(d)
        result.append(d)
    else:
        d = (3*d)+1    
    #cpt += 1
#print(*result, end=' ')

for n in result[n-1:]:      # list is 0-based. 
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a counter, and only start printing once the counter is reached:

```py
i = 0
while d != 1:
    if (d % 2 == 0): #% checks remainder, if 0 - odd, if 1 - even 
        d = d/2
        i = i + 1
        if i >= n:
            print(d)
    else:
        d = (3*d)+1
    cpt+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `n` for that purpose:

```
print('choose two whole numbers')
d = int(input("d: "))
n = int(input("n: "))
cpt=0
while d != 1:
    if (d % 2 == 0): #% checks remainder, if 0 - odd, if 1 - even 
        d = d/2
        n -= 1
        if n <= 0:
            print(d)
    else:
        d = (3*d)+1    
    cpt+=1
    
print('d is reached at '+str(cpt)+'th term')
```